# Is it possible to upload file with selenium through anchor tag?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, anchor

I have an upload file button looks like this: `<a href="javascript:void('');"></a>`

Trying to upload file through it using `sendKeys()` method.
But I get errors *cannot focus on element*. Is there's a workaround or the way to upload file with `<a>` tag?

I use this:

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("//a[@title='Upload an image']").get(0).sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\files\image.jpg");
```

Tried also to `click()`, to `moveToElement(element).build().perform()` to focus on the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** it won't be possible to upload a file with selenium through **`<a>`** tag.

File uploading is achieved through:

- **`<input>`** tags.
- These **`<input>`** tags needs focus before being filled up by any *character sequence*

On the contrary,

- The **attributes** of an **`<a>`** tag are are as follows:

  - **`charset`**: Defines the character encoding of the linked document.
  - **`coords`**: Specifies the coordinates appropriate to the shape attribute to define a region of an image for image maps
  - **`href`**:  Specifies the URL of a page or the name of the anchor that the link goes to.
  - **`hreflang`**: Language code of the destination URL.
  - **`name`**: Marks an area of the page that a link jumps to.
  - **`rel`**: Describes the relationship between the current document and the destination URI.
  - **`rev`**: Specifies the relationship between the target URL and the current document.
  - **`shape`**: Specifies the shape of the image map.
  - **`target`**: Where to open the target URL.
  - **`type`**: Specifies the MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) type of the target URL
  - **`accesskey`**: Access keys (or shortcut keys).
  - **`class`**: Document wide identifier.
  - **`dir`**: Specifies the direction of the text.
  - **`id`**: Document wide identifier.
  - **`tabindex`**:  Helps determine the tabbing order when the user 'tabs' through the elements on the page.
  - **`title`**: Specifies a title to associate with the element.
  - **`style`**: Helps to include inline casecadubf style sheet.
  - **`lang`**: Sets the language code.
- The **event attributes** of an **`<a>`** tag are are as follows:

  - **`onfocus`**: Script runs when the element gets focus.
  - **`onblur`**: Script runs when the element loses focus.
  - **`onclick`**:   Script runs when a mouse click.
  - **`ondblclick`**: Script runs when a mouse double-click.
  - **`onmousedown`**: Script runs when mouse button is pressed.
  - **`onmouseup`**: Script runs when mouse button is released.
  - **`onmouseover`**: Script runs when mouse pointer moves over an element.
  - **`onmousemove`**: Script runs when mouse pointer moves.
  - **`onmouseout`**: Script runs when mouse pointer moves out of an element.
  - **`onkeypress`**: Script runs when key is pressed and released.
  - **`onkeydown`**: Script runs when key is pressed.
  - **`onkeyup`**: Script runs when key is released.

So, ideally the **`<a>`** tags should also be able to receive the **focus**.

But as you are seeing an error as *...cannot focus on element...* it may be due to other factors which is *out of scope* for this question.

### Conclusion

File uploading have to be done through **`<input>`** tags only.

### Reference

- [Anchors](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html)
- [HTML A tag](http://www.mytoptutorials.com/html/tag/anchor-tag-event-attributes/)

Comment: @Maybellene Updated the answer with more details and reference. Upvote the answer if this/any  answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.